# FCM push notification not working when app is closed and user on another apps in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, ios-background-mode

I had implemented FCM in flutter. In android push notification is working fine in all modes(foreground, background and terminated). And in iOS push notification is working fine in all modes(foreground, background and terminated). but issue is when we are on another app like safari or Gmail or any other app then no notification coming in iOS. Please help me out of this kind of issue.

I had added Push Notification, background fetch and remote notification in capabilities sections. but nothing will happen